# How to make text hidden or revealed when inside or outside a <div>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some text like this:

```
Once upon a time, <div class="light">there lived</div> a cat.
The <div class="light">cat liked</div> to watch fish swim.
```

I need to place some text, in a `<div>` e.g. `<div class="hidden_when_inside">text</div>` which is hidden if placed inside `<div class="light">`, but not hidden when outside. E.g.:

```
Once upon a time, <div class="light">there <div class="hidden_when_inside">this text is invisible</div> lived</div> a cat.
The <div class="light">cat liked</div> to watch <div class="hidden_when_inside">this text is visible</div>fish swim.
```

Similarly, some text placed in `<div class="hidden_when_outside">` will be hidden only when outside of `<div class="light">`.

Here hidden means:

- The text cannot be seen.
- The text cannot be selected.
- The text occupies no space.
- The text does not interfere with the formatting of the other text.

Is there any way to hide or reveal text depending on whether or not it appears within another `<div>`?

Answer (score 3):

Use the parent selector to hidden the inside element like below.

```
 .light .hidden_when_inside{display:none}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljdtg48b/1/)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using pure css using the child selector `>` (note this will only effect immediate children so if the use case is that `.hidden_when_inside` can be nested several layers deep inside a `.light` then go with `.light .hidden_when_inside`)

```css
.light > .hidden_when_inside{
  display:none
    }
```

```html
Once upon a time, <div class="light">there <div class="hidden_when_inside">this text is invisible</div> lived</div> a cat.
The <div class="light">cat liked</div> to watch <div class="hidden_when_inside">this text is visible</div>fish swim.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display it later, you need to dive into JavaScript, for instance:

```
document.getElementByTagName('hidden_when_inside').onclick = function() {

var className = ' ' + myButton.className + ' ';

this.className = ~className.indexOf(' active ') ?
                     className.replace(' active ', ' ') :
                     this.className + ' active';
```

}